# How to access static class member from instance?

Tags: typescript

What is the best way to access a static member on a class from an instance of that class?

I want to be able to have shared values across all instances of a class be static on the class, and be able to refer to them from the instance.

There seems to be many janky ways of doing this, but none of them elegant IMO.

For example:

```
class BagOfCoins {
    static MAX_COINS = 9999;
}

const bag = new BagOfCoins();

// Method 1
// Almost works, but errors with "Property 'MAX_COINS' does not exist on type 'Function'.", but it still has a value of 9999 when compiled.
console.log(bag.constructor.MAX_COINS);

// Method 2
// Works, but looks awful and only works because it just confuses TS.
console.log(bag.constructor.prototype.constructor.MAX_COINS); 

// Method 3
// Basically the same thing, TS still has no idea what the properties of `constructor` are so doesn't provide member suggestions.
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(bag).constructor.MAX_COINS);
```

Method 4

```
class BagOfCoins {
    // Add a reference to the class itself to each instance.
    Class = BagOfCoins;

    static MAX_COINS = 9999;
}

const bag = new BagOfCoins();

// Wastes more memory for an extra member that it already has access to by other means...
console.log(bag.Class.MAX_COINS);
```

Method 5

```
type Writable<T> = {-readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K]};

class BagOfCoins {
    readonly MAX_COINS!: number;
}
// Emulate static membership by moving it to the class prototype.
(BagOfCoins.prototype as Writable<BagOfCoins>).MAX_COINS = 9999;

const bag = new BagOfCoins();

// Adds a lot of extra syntax for defining such members, and need to move the initialisation out of the class itself, which looks awful.
console.log(bag.MAX_COINS);
```

Is there a more user-friendly way of doing this that doesn't require adding a lot of confusing bloat?

**EDIT:**

Some answers & comments seem to be getting distracted by the low-hanging fruit answer of `BagOfCoins.MAX_COINS`.

Consider the following example use for when you might not know the specific class that a instance is made from, but you do know that the class has the static property you want to access defined on it:

```
class Weapon {
    static DAMAGE = 1;
}

class Spear extends Weapon {
}

class Sword extends Weapon {
    static DAMAGE = 4;
}

const Weapons: {[key: string]: typeof Weapon} = {
    Spear,
    Sword,
    // etc. may be a dynamically generated list from data loaded from some config file.
};

class Loadout {
    weapon: Weapon;

    constructor(weapon: Weapon) {
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }
}

const loadout1 = new Loadout(new Weapons.Spear());
const loadout2 = new Loadout(new Weapons.Sword());
// and so on...

// Comment by jcalz adds another method, by using a parent class that has the desired static property, i.e. Weapon.
// Method 6
// Best one so far I guess, a bit better looking than the others IMO, but does allow proper property suggestions.
console.log((loadout1.weapon.constructor as typeof Weapon).DAMAGE); // 1
console.log((loadout2.weapon.constructor as typeof Weapon).DAMAGE); // 4
```

Comment: What's wrong with `BagOfCoins.MAX_COINS` ?

Comment: Yes, what is wrong with `BagOfCoins.MAX_COINS`? Are you going to have subclasses or something?  If not, just use `BagOfCoins` instead of `this.constructor`.  If you are going to have subclasses, then you will probably need `(this.constructor as typeof BagOfCoins).MAX_COINS` due to a limitation in TS around strong constructor types (see [ms/TS#3841](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841)).  Do you want this written up as an answer?

Comment: @Psidom See edit for what is wrong with `BagOfCoins.MAX_COINS`.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah sure. I stumbled on that topic myself after a while.

Comment: So, should I write up an answer that talks about the issues (including the current state of ms/TS#3841) and what the workarounds are?

Answer (score 0):

Practically, you can't access static members on an instance because they belong to the class and not accessible on the instance of the class:

```
class Cow {
  static NUMBER_OF_HORNS = 2
}
// usage would go like this:
let horns = Cow.NUMBER_OF_HORNS // 2
const ankole = new Cow()
ankole.NUMBER_OF_HORNS // this will never work, NUMBER_OF_HORNS is a     static property
```

Comment: It doesn't really look like you're engaging with the question as asked. In JavaScript you can write `ankole.constructor.NUMBER_OF_HORNS`, because the static side of a class is indeed accessible from the instance.  You can't write `ankole.NUMBER_OF_HORNS`, but that's not what the question is trying to do, so the fact that this doesn't work seems beside the point.  Can you clarify how this addresses the question?